# Git Lens for VS Code icons

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitlens

Anyone know what the green + and orange horizontal rectangle and vertical line icons are?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The orange icon shows that the file has been renamed.
- The green icon shows that the file has been added.

See all the other icons [here](https://github.com/gitkraken/vscode-gitlens/tree/main/images/dark).

Comment: The list of icons is literally just a list of icons. There's no explanation as to what each icon means.